# Number of days in the months corresponding to selected dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to find the number of days as days from months chosen between two dates. For example, if I choose date1 as January 1,2021 and date2 as March 1, 2021, then I need to get the total number of days in January, February and March.

Output=

Number of days in january + Number of days in february + Number of days in march = 31+28+31

What I tried:

```
const getDiff=(selectedDate1,selectedDate2)=>{
    console.log('Date check',moment(selectedDate1).daysInMonth(),moment(new Date()).daysInMonth())
    if(moment(selectedDate1).daysInMonth() - moment(selectedDate2).daysInMonth() ===0){
      return Number(moment(selectedDate1).daysInMonth())
    }else{
      return Number(moment(selectedDate1).daysInMonth())+Number(moment(selectedDate2).daysInMonth())
    }
  }
```

But with this code, i am getting only the sum of days of the selected dates, ie. only Number of days in January + Number of days in March

Comment: question updated! I missed the codes. Thanks for reminding

Comment: OMG - you're using moment! You're making this way too hard. Just use moment! You can either use [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) or [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using moment.js, you just get the difference between start of the start month and end of the end month in days plus 1 (because the end of month won't include the last day and adding 1 is simpler than going to the start of the following month), e.g.

```js
function wholeMonthDays(d1, d2) {
  let diff = moment(d2).endOf('month').diff(moment(d1).startOf('month'),'days') + 1; 
  return diff;
}

let start = new Date(2021,0,21);
let end = new Date(2021,2,11);

console.log(wholeMonthDays(start, end)); // 90
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can go to the start of the month after *end* to get the difference:

```js
function wholeMonthDays(d1, d2) {
  let start = moment(d1).startOf('month');
  let end = moment(d2).startOf('month').add(1, 'month');
  let diff = end.diff(start, 'days');
  return diff;
}

let start = new Date(2021, 0, 21);
let end = new Date(2021, 2, 11);

console.log(wholeMonthDays(start, end)); // 90
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I've set the dates to during the month to show that it adds the "days in months" rather than just the difference between the two dates.

If you actually want an array of the total days in each month, just set the start to the end of the month, get the  date, add one month, set to the end of the month, etc. until you've gone past the end month.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. Remember that Months in Java and JavaScript are (moronically) 0-based. So month 1 is February
2. To get the number of days in a month you can use a Date object and go to the first of the next month, then substract 1 day, then call getDay.
3. The time between two dates in milliseconds is

   ```
   var d1 = ...;
   var d2 = ...;
   var duration = Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
   ```

You can then divide `duration` by milliseconds (1000), seconds (60), minutes (60) etc to get the timespan in the unites you'd

Comment: Surprise! OP is using moment. LOL.

Comment: Days aren't always 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so dividing the difference by ms in one day doesn't always work in difficult to find cases.

Comment: FYI… In Java *legacy* classes, the month number is zero-based. Those terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes that use sane numbering: 1-12 for months January-December.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be:

```
// 'lo' and 'hi' could be of type Date or numbers coming from Date.getTime()
const daysBetween = (lo, hi) => {
    const oneDayInMilliseconds
        = 1000 // one sec has 1000 millis
        * 3600 // one hour has 3600 seconds
        * 24;  // one day has 24 hours
    return (hi - lo) / oneDayInMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: Days are not always 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed. The OP wants the number of days in the months, not days between dates (which has been answered many times before).